# update page right after response, no client callback

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

My question is theorical and I've no use case for it *yet* and I didn't find any post on SO about it which is surprising. That said I want to load data on a page after the page has been sent to the end user. I'm asking how can one do it after the page has been sent. Not with a javascript callback like remote command. Time is lost if it's done like that.

For example let's say the main data for the page sent to the user takes 1 second to load and the data I want to update takes 1.5 seconds. I'd like the response to start after 1 second. And the the page of the user being updated .5 seconds after he receives the initial page.

If the timeline using remote command is like this:

page rendered on the server -> server sends response -> transfer 1 second -> javascript callback -> transfer 1 second -> data fetched on the server -> server sends response -> transfer 1 second -> rendered on end user page.

There is a grand total of 2 seconds of delay from the point the user receives the page and the page is upated. If the data was sent right after the response I would expect a 0.5 seconds delay.

Comment: I guess that does it. In your example you omitted the part which pushes the data to the page (so an update is necessary)? If that's the case then great it's even better than what I was hoping for and I actually have an use for this. I thought I had to go through a phaseListenner for some reason.

Comment: I don't get it. Your response starts when all the data is in the bean right ? If that's the case I thought my question was clear but I want the response to take place independantely of a set of data that I'll push when it's ready. But I guess your answer might be enough for me to go in the right direction.